# nginx image behaves differently in kubectl deployment and pods

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I am using nginx image to create pods as follows -

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 -- /bin/sh -c 'sleep 20000'
$ kubectl create deployment nginx-deploy --image=nginx --port=80 --replicas=1
```

These results two pods as follows -

```
$ kubectl get pods
nginx                           1/1     Running   0          24s
nginx-deploy-7496796997-wkhv8   1/1     Running   0          19s
```

the curl connects to localhost in the "nginx-deploy" pod whereas in other pod it does not.

```
$ kubectl  exec -it nginx -- /bin/sh -c 'curl localhost'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
$ k exec -it nginx-deploy-7496796997-wkhv8 -- /bin/sh -c 'curl localhost'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
....
```

Any reason nginx image is behaving differently in these two pods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Here command = /bin/sh -c 'sleep 20000'
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 -- command
```

When you create a pod using the command, it will overwrite command in Dockerfile. So that nginx server will not be started in the pod. Please refer to the Dockerfile of nginx.

> 1. Have not defined COMMAND and ARGS in Kubernetes, use Dockerfile's config.
> 2. Have defined COMMAND (no effect if ARGS defined or not) in Kubernetes, use Kubernetes COMMAND.
> 3. Have not defined COMMAND but ARGS in Kubernetes, use ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile and ARGS in Kubernetes.

[image]

In summary, Kubernetes has higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/sh -c 'sleep 20000'`

Your command has overridden the default CMD/ENTRYPOINT defined in nginx image. As a result, the nginx server will not start. If you `kubectl run` again without your command, the nginx will run like the deployment.